# `$` not working in jQuery. `noConflict()` is not being called anywhere

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I was working on a PhoneGap app and left for the day. When I came back the next day I kept getting errors. Turns out that `$(document)` is returning null, but `jQuery(document)` is not. From what I've read on here it means that something else is overwriting the `$` sign.
But, I've tried commenting out all the includes for javascript files except for jQuery and jQueryMobile and it still happens. I've also done a global search for `noConflict` and the only place it was found was in the jQuery js file.

Does anybody know what else might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had added a small utility function that was causing the error:

```
function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why this is happening, and probably no-one will know without looking at your code.

However, here is an easy way to overcome it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // now in here you can us the $ as you would before
    // eg:
    $('div').css({"background-color":"blue"});
});
```

I do this as standard on all jQuery projects I'm working on so that there is never any conflict with using the `$` variable.